# How to use variable names without overriding a module name?

Tags: design-patterns, lua

`math.random()` works out of the box, but if I set `math` to something else it breaks

`local math = 1 + 1 -- set math to something else
math.random() -- breaks`

is there any way to make `math.random()` still work while setting `local math = 1 + 1`?

I have a bunch of modules with dot-notation functions such as `coord.get()` or `offset.get()`

but then those base words like `coord` and `offset` become unusable for variable names, which is annoying

Comment: `_G.math.random()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With properly written module you can do `local coords = require("coord")`

This would create a local variable `coords` so that when `coord` is shaded by your later local definition you can still access the functions through `coords`. If the module does not return the table it creates and only makes it globally this will not work.

same would work for math.random `local random = math.random` if it is defined before your `local math` variable.

```
local random = math.random
local math = 1 + 1

print(random(math))
```

Alternatively you can put the whole lib into a local variable like this:

```
local maths = math
local math = 1 + 1

print(maths.random(math))
```

That said it is not likely that a number variable called `math` is well named. Something like `product` would be more appropriate name, given your example.

Comment: local coords refers to the module. you do not put the module into it...

Answer (score 2):

You can always require the module again:

```
require("math").random()
```

Since the module has already been loaded, this is not very expensive.